# How to setup Products and Price books ? - Complex Scenario (Professional Edition)

Tags: pricebook, professional-edition, pricebookentry

All SF lovers,

We wanted to use SFDC products/pricebooks to setup `products & services` and planning to go with Professional Edition.

For Services, we have a standard delivery fee for the services rendered which are in in 50:30:20 payment model.

For products (**fixed revenue model**), we have a flat fee, maintenance fee & hosting fee on monthly basis.

For products (**transaction model**), we have transaction fee based on the transaction volume and transaction fee and with tiered pricing.

For example:

**Scenario #1.** Customer A wish to buy A using fixed revenue model. So Total Revenue from Product A will be Delivery Fee (50:30:20) plus Monthly Fixed (Flat+Maintenance+Hosting)

**Scenario#2.** Customer B wish to buy same Product A using transaction model. So Total Revenue from Product A will be Delivery Fee (50:30:20) + Monthly Variable (Transaction Fee times Transaction Fee) plus Monthly Fixed (Maintenance+Hosting)

**Scenario#3.** Customer C wish to buy same Product A using Fixed revenue model for 1st Year and transaction model from 2nd year onwards. This scenario is combination of **Scenario#1 & Scenario#2**. 
So Total Revenue from Product A will be revenue from scenario#1 for 1st year plus revenue from scenario#2 from 2nd year onwards

**Scenario#4.** Similar to **Scenario#2 & Scenario#3** following transaction model but the transaction fee will be tiered.
0 - 100K transaction will be $1 per transaction 
Above 100K transaction will be $0.90, per transaction

Have no problem setting up the fixed revenue products in SFDC.

How to setup the products transaction model in SFDC(products & pricebook)?
How to setup services with 50:30:20 payment model in SFDC(products & pricebook)?

Any suggestion on how best to setup the products & pricebooks?

(FYI, I have already received some suggestion to go with CPQ solution. But we would like to explore whether it will be possible with SFDC native products & pricebooks.)

Appreciate your help on this.
(As suggested, amended the request with more clarity)

Comment: Your question is too broad but this tutorial of mine will help you answer your question on "how best to setup the products & pricebooks?" [Price Books and Product Schedules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4St6U3xypE)

Comment: Rob, despite being closed, this is an interesting question, we are also dealing with right now. you said "Have no problem setting up the fixed revenue products in SFDC." - how did you setup the multiple fees? via separate, dedicated products?